# Restricting web api deployed in App Engine Flex from outside

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app-engine-flexible

I have a web api that's been deployed on google cloud's app engine flex. The primary function of this service is to call another service (within the same google cloud project) every 4 hours via google cloud scheduler.

Since this service is purely automated, I'd like to restrict anybody from being able to hit it's endpoint externally. I know that public IP addresses can be removed from VM instances in Compute Engine, but how do I do that in GAE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can restrict the access to you App Engine Flex application using firewall rules. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/creating-firewalls) you have the documentation for controlling the access to your application using Firewall Rules.

Another option is enabaling IAP ( [Identity-Aware Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/app-engine-quickstart#enabling_iap) ). Afterwards you will need to configure your another service to be able to connect through IAP and nobody else will have access to your app.

Comment: Hey thanks. I noticed that cron services run on 10.0.0.1 and 0.1.0.40 ip addresses but what about the actual services themselves? Where can I see the ip addresses for them?

Comment: On reading more about it, it seems that a combination of your answer and looking at X- headers coming from the cron job are the way to go to prevent external users accessing the endpoint. Thanks again!